# how to use variable from function

Tags: python-3.x

`def message(number):`

```
    `number+=2`
     print(number)
     ans = message(number)
     return number`
```

`if ans == 3:`

```
`print("theory was right")`
```

`number=1234`

`message(1)`

`print(number)`

In the above code, I am not able to use variable returned from def() out of the function body. Is there a way I can do it? Pls. don't mind indents coz this is my first post here. thnx

I've tried
`ans = number`
also
`ans = message()`
but still not able to do get the output

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `message` calls `message`, so that's an infinite recursion. You try and check `ans` before the function has even been called.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368)

Comment: *Pls. don't mind indents* - not possible if you're dealing with Python mate...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you build an infinite recursion - if you want to use a function inside itself, you have to insert a condition which will stop the recursion and let you get a result.

So, above `ans = message(number)`, you should place `if` statement.

---

Secondly, you cannot use a variable out of a function, if it is not returned - it has never been counted.

You probably got confused it with possibilty of using `global` variables out of loops.

---

To sum up, if you want to check `ans`, you have to return it in a function and call the function like this (it is not the solution):

```
def function(x):
    ans = message(number)
    return ans

if funcion(x):
    print("theory was right")
```